# Is it possible to return from a method to lets say

Tags: java, exception, methods, return

There are 3 methods as f1, f2 and f3. I want to return from f3 to f1.

Assumptions:

> Initially f1 calls f2
>
> f2 calls f3.
>
> Try catch block should be used in all of the three functions.

The case is if I get an exception in f3 then I should be able to return to f1.

Thanks.

Comment: Try/finally is your friend.

Comment: If I use try catch in f3 and If I put return in catch of f3. Then it is returning to f2. What I want is without any conditional checking it should be able to return to f1.

Comment: You should implement some status flag to determine when to return from f2 to f1, but that does require conditional checking.

Comment: [your anwer](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J5a_ExceptionAssert.html)

Comment: @ExtremeCoders I'm trying to avoid to use the status flag because the number of functions that are in the same level as f3 are numerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
catch(Exception e) { 
return;
}
```

You can catch the exception in f2 and add return so it will go to f1. or just don't catch the exception in f2 (just add throws in f2) and let it propagate to f1.

Answer (score 3):

try..

```
void f1(){

try{
f2();
}catch(Exception er){}
system.out.println("Exception...");

}

void f2() throws Exception{

f3();

}

void f3() throws Exception{

//on some condition
throw new Exception("something failed");

}
```

Comment: I've edited the question, please take a look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public void f1(){
    f2();
    // f3 failed. other code here
}

public void f2(){
    try {
        f3();
    } catch (Exception e){
        // Log your exception here
    }
    return;
}

public void f3(){
    throw new Exception("Error:");
}
```

Comment: Try catch block should be used in all the functions

Comment: Its not needed. In f2, you will log the error and f2 returns. Then remaining part of f1 gets executed

Answer (score 0):

Check something like this

```
void f1() throws Exception {

    try {
        f2();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Exception Ocuured");
    }


}

void f2() throws Exception {
    try {
        f3();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Exception Ocuured");
    }
}

void f3() throws Exception {

    try {

        // Do Some work here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        f1();


    }
}
```

Comment: Calling f1() in catch block of f3() executes the statements in f1 from beginning. After executing it returns to f3 and f3 returns to f2, statements in f2 after the statement in which we called f3 will get executed, after that it returns to f1. This is not the behavior I need. Thanks.